# Adjusting Print Page in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, printing

I have some printed form on paper and want to create a web page (result of a report) and put those pre-printed pages in printer and print web page for fill the blanks on paper.

What is the best way to adjust the location of contents in the web page to work with any printer correctly?

thnx for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just generating a regular html webpage to print, you're going to have a very hard time getting it consistent across multiple computers (or browsers, or printers).  There are lots of browser settings that affect how the webpage is printed...like margins, header/footer text, etc. and these aren't things you can control from the html page.

You would need to generate a formatted file so there is less room for interpretation by the computer/browser/printer.  Something like a PDF where you can create more consistent output.

I had a similar requirement for an app a while back.  The requirements for that project were such that we generated a MS Word document prefilled with content (text, tables, etc.), then the user opens that generated file and prints it or saves it.  I would think a PDF would be desirable in most cases though.

Comment: I suppose if all the people printing the html webpage were using the same browser, OS and printer and you could guarantee the browser and printer settings are the same across all, then printing the html page may work.  Though this seems unlikely and highly error prone going forward.

Comment: Some good tips:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164197/printing-labels-from-asp-net-page